# How to update a library through drush or git url? what about update chosen library?

Tags: drush, installation, updating, version-control, theming

I am new with Drush and git... previously I use to work with Ftp so at the moment I would like to know How I can update a common library by using drush or by using git (library url).

I know that in order to update a module I can use: `drush up module_name` How about for libraries?

I tried to do the same for libraries but it did not work.... I know some libraries have their own drush command for download it like is the case of chosen library:

```
drush chosenplugin
```

however I have in my local machine a Drupal profile that I am all the time updating it so the profile of course has not `sites/all/libraries` but has `profiles/libraries/` the problem in this case is that when running `drush chosenplugin` the console shows up:

```
Unable to unzip chosen_v1.1.0.zip   error
```

and I think it shows that error because according to the chosen module/library drupal site information https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen what the drush chosenplugin does is:

> The command will download the plugin and unpack it in
>   "sites/all/libraries". It is possible to add another path as an option
>   to the command, but not recommended unless you know what you are
>   doing.

So of course in this case I dont have `sites/all/libraries` and that´s why I think the command is not getting success with the download/update?

Is there a way how to add another path? how to add it in order my chosen library gets updated in the path `profiles/libraries/`.

Please keep in mind that I have already a `chosen library version v0.9.1 installed` and now what I want is to **update** `it to the last version which one is v1.1.0.`

So how I update it if I have `profiles/libraries` as path and **not** `sites/all/libraries`?

- The library belongs to the drupal profile.

I run `drush help chosenplugin` but it only says:

> Arguments: path Optional. A path where to install the chosen plugin.
>   If committed Drush will use the default location.

I know that the default location is `sites/libraries` BUT IN MY CASE the **PATH** would be: `profiles/myprofile/libraries/chosen` SO in this case if I do the libray update with the command `drush chosenplugin` then how I set up the path in this command? the help just says that i can use `path` as `argument` but **does not say how to set it..**.

**If there is no way to update it through drush then please provideme a guide how to update the chosen library by using git... knowing that the library url in git is: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen.git**

PLEASE HELP!!!!! :)

Thank you everyone!!!

Liz

Comment: if the library is not part of the profile, you can have it in all/libraries as well - just make sure the folder exists. try running drush with the -d switch, that will give us more info about the problem. also try `drush help chosenplugin` - apparently you can give it the path as argument.

Comment: Problem is that library is part of the profile. I run drush help chosenplugin but it also says: Arguments: path      Optional. A path where to install the chosen plugin. If ommited Drush will use the default location.

Comment: Problem is that library is part of the profile. I run `drush help chosenplugin` but it also says: `Arguments: path      Optional. A path where to install the chosen plugin. If committed Drush will use the default location.` I know that the default location is `sites/libraries` BUT IN MY CASE the PATH would be: `profiles/myprofile/libraries/chosen`    SO in this case if I do the libray update with the command `drush chosenplugin` then how I set up the `path` in this command? the help just says that i can use `path` as argument but does not says how to set it... please help!!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: `drush chosenplugin --path=profiles/myprofile/libraries/chosen`